# How do I specify the tag to use for an image within a VS Code container definition JSON?

Tags: image, docker, visual-studio-code, tags, containers

VS Code fails to start if I specify a tag when using a preexisting docker image, as in:

```
    {
        "name": "VsCode Image Tag Issue.",
        "context": "..",
        "image": "rirlswift/vscode-remote-nvidia-issue:latest",
        "runArgs": [
             "--name","docker-opengl"
            "-v", "/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw",
            "-e", "DISPLAY",
            "--rm"
        ],
        "postCreateCommand": "glxgears"
    }
```

Here is the issue mark down from the issue I've submitted to the VS Code remote extensions team. [2431](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2431)

Is there possibly a syntax for image that I have missions?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Looks like a fix is pending from VsCode: 
[2431](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2431)
I have verified using insiders edition

```
Version: 1.45.0-insider
```